# Phpstorm does not see xdebug but it is installed

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

PhpStorm cannot see xdebug but it is installed. In my browser xdebug works fine. Where is the problem?

The error:

> Connection with 'xdebug' was not established. Validate installation.

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.coverage_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

`phpinfo` in phpstorm:

PHP version: 5.4.10

```
Loaded extensions:  bcmath, bz2, calendar, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, ereg, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, gettext, hash, iconv, imap, json, ldap, libxml, mbstring, mcrypt, mysql, mysqli, openssl, pcre, PDO, pdo_mysql, pdo_pgsql, pdo_sqlite, pgsql, Phar, posix, Reflection, session, SimpleXML, soap, sockets, SPL, sqlite3, standard, tokenizer, XCache, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xsl, yaz, zip, zlib
```

Comment: There could be different `php.ini` files, one for web server, another for CLI PHP interpreter. Make sure that xdebug is enabled in all the `php.ini` files for the PHP versions that you are using.

Comment: Can you show us your PHP Web Application Run/Debug configuration in PHPStorm, including server configuration?

Comment: So .. what `.ini` file you have edited? Please give **full** name. It's also possible that you have more than one PHP executable in your system and wrong one is used when run from PhpStorm 9and therefore, wrong .ini file was loaded).

Comment: Configuration File /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini

Comment: Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0-komodo, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

Comment: OK. Now run **`php --ini`** and see what it says (what config file it loads) -- but you must run it from **within** PhpStorm (Tools | Run Command -- you may need to provide FULL path to the php binary)

Comment: Have a look at this link as well -- some of the articles are referring to different locations of php.ini (but, possibly, it is different now in newer version): http://peterleong.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/mamp-phpstorm-5-and-xdebug.html

Comment: LazyOne  /private/etc/php.ini ))) How can I chenge it?

Comment: How can I chenge it Loaded Configuration File:         /private/etc/php.ini to File /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini

Comment: I'm not Mac user and never worked with MAMP. But you may use **1)** symlink so both files would have the same content .. or just edit THAT file instead; **2)** there _should be_ some environment variable that tells PHP where to load config file from (check `PHPRC` -- at least it works on Windows); **3)** If you delete (make backup first) that file .. **maybe** it will pick up your one in /Library/... folder. **In any case:** you now know the reason -- you should find workaround for this behaviour.

Comment: I got this problem too. And i'm sure my xDebug is work normally. i tries to use var_dump(), it displayed formatted by xDebug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, are you using MAMP (free) or MAMP Pro?

Turns out there is a difference between the php.ini file you edit from MAMP and the php.ini file that PhpStorm uses in the interpreter.

The MAMP Pro php.ini file resides in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini` and doesn't have a PHP installation (which PhpStorm needs when setting the interpreter). If you run phpinfo(); this is the file you will see data from.

When you set PhpStorm to the necessary location here `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.x/bin` it looks at the php.ini file there, not the one that MAMP Pro uses (above). So if you want PhpStorm to see the debugger, you need to add the code to that php.ini file.

[image: PhpStorm Interpreter Settings]

For help setting up the interpreter for MAMP and PhpStorm refer to the [documentation here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+MAMP+with+PhpStorm+IDE)

**HELPFUL HINT:** When checking to see if xdebug is installed make sure to run the `--version` command in terminal from the MAMP php location. Otherwise you'll end up seeing the default OSX PHP info which wouldn't have xdebug installed by default.

Example: run this in the PhpStorm terminal to see if it works `/Applications/Mamp/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php --version`

Answer (score 9):

MAMP using different php.ini if you run it from terminal, try this code to find the php.ini

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

After that add the code for activate the xDebug

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000
```

If this work, please consider accept the answer for the benefit the others.

Comment: @imRcH on PHPStorm, check your PHPInterpreter, did you select the right PHP Version? Try to run the command i gave in PHPStorm console command.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Mac OS X has php installed by default. There are two ini files for MAMP PRO.

PhpStorm will run the default php which you do not add the xdebug function to it.

Read this post for the solution

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5466653

Pay attention to the STEP 5

===================================

okay, if it do not work, I thought u may not pay enough attention to the article, It do helpful and explain the reason, read i again ?

Comment: We don't really like link only answers here, please copy the relevant constant from the link into your answer.

Comment: The link was exactly what I needed, and has very detailed instructions.  Thank you for sharing.

Comment: If there is the rules of stackoverflow, I will comply to it, But the reason of the question is so long. so i think u

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

I did:

1. Installed xdebug by following the steps [here](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php).
2. Found out which version of PHP does my PHPStorm use.
3. Created a new entry in the corresponding php.ini file of the `/path/to/xdebug/modules/xdebug.so`.

and I was able to solve my problem. **xdebug** is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in that it worked then it did not.

In my case, the cause turned out to be an miss placed `.htaccess` file in the root of the project.

The `.htaccess` file (repeated below) was there from a previous set of testing and was intended to stop XDebug from working. It sure did.

```
php_value xdebug.remote_autostart 0
php_value xdebug.remote_enable 0
php_value xdebug.profiler_enable 0
```

I just renamed the file and like magic, all was good.