# XDebug not working after Homebrew install

Tags: php, apache, osx-mavericks, homebrew, xdebug

I'm trying to get xdebug set up on my local OS 10.9 dev environment but without much success. I installed it using homebrew and it seemed to install ok. In terminal it seems to be loading ok, `php -i` loads `Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini` and further down shows info about xdebug but `phpinfo()` in my `index.php` file seems to load a different `php.ini` located at `/etc/php.ini`.

Why are there 2 different php.ini files and which one should I use? How do I change to the appropriate file?

I've been googling and fiddling for 3 hours now and can't figure it out... Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

I tried to add:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-xdebug/xdebug.so"
```

to the `/etc/php.ini` file but it had no effect. The file path is verified to be correct.

Comment: Please read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236845/phpstorm-does-not-see-xdebug-but-it-is-installed

Comment: @imRcH Thanks for the response. I had a look through that post but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: `php -i` is CLI and may have complete different .inis, also try the [wizard](http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is of benefit to someone else, here is how I got xdebug working.

I didn't realise that homebrew installed a separate new version of php and didn't update `httpd.conf` so until I figured this out, I was loading the wrong php module in my `httpd.conf`.

When I changed this to the homebrew built module, everything worked as expected.